# How to get the SQL result in reverse from the columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I have been asked a question in an interview.

Sample table named `test`:

```
A|| B
---------- -
1 | a
2 | b
3 | c
4 | d
```

Desired output:

```
A || B
------- -
1 | d
2 | c
3 | b
4 | a
```

How to to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use order by on column B `ASC|DESC`

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Testcol DESC) as A, B
FROM Table
ORDER BY B DESC;
```

Comment: but it will also sort the data for a also  right 4,3,2,1 ?

Comment: oh I thought A was the table name and 1,2,3,4 was the row count, sorry I'll think about this some more

Comment: select Row num over order by column B desc as A, B ?